# GUI for transforming Java Bytecode based on decompiled source?

Tags: disassembly, decompilation, java, byte-code, jar

Okay. So I've just come up with the most amazing program for java developers and reverse-engineerers and I was wondering if something like the following program already exists:

What I'm thinking of is like a middle-ground between something like [DirtyJOE](http://dirty-joe.com/) and a Java Decompiler.

I already know that:

- It's possible to inject and manipulate code in a compiled class using [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org)
- You can decompile an unobfuscated jar into a readable and understandable state
- It's practical to explore and edit a class using a GUI because DirtyJOE can do that amazingly well

So is there some sort of program that can show me a decompiled class and allow me to manipulate/inject into different parts of it individually?

For example, I would like replace one method with my own or change a field's access within a compiled class file.

So basically I'm looking for a frontend for ASM built with an interface based on decompiled source code.

Does this exist? If not, what's the closest thing I'm going to get to it?

Comment: Have you tried IDA Pro?

Comment: Can IDA actually edit stuff, though? I've never really used IDA that much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using javasnoop (https://code.google.com/p/javasnoop/) to accomplish something similar.

Here's a tutorial for using it -

http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/hacking-java-applications-using-javasnoop/

Comment: After looking at a video showcasing JavaSnoop, I have now decided that it is by far the coolest program in existence. However, I can't seem to get the "Attach to existing process" working. Thinking it was my JRE, I tried 32xJRE7, 64xJRE7, 64xJDK7, and 64xJDK6 (all of which didn't let me attach onto any of the applets or programs I had running in the background). Currently, I'm using reJ (from Extreme Coders' answer), but this program seems like it would benefit me much more.

Comment: Have you had a look in the Readme (https://javasnoop.googlecode.com/svn-history/r32/trunk/resources/README.txt) for Javasnoop ? It lists a number of steps required to setup Javasnoop correctly. Other than those steps, maybe you could try running it with Admin privileges ?

Comment: I had to specifically run the bat file from an Administrator command prompt. I was trying to right-click on the bat file and select "Run as Administrator." That didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Some tools you can use. However note that *none* of them has the ability to recompile classes, i.e you cannot decompile a single class to source, modify it, and then recompile back. It may be possible using [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) but then you need to do a lot of modification on the decompiled source itself. Other ways may be to decompile the entire bunch of classes and then recompile all when done.

> **[Class Editor](http://classeditor.sourceforge.net/)**
>
> This is a tool to open Java class file binaries, view their internal
>   structure, modify portions of it if required and save the class file
>   back. It also generates readable reports similar to the javap utility.
>   Easy to use Java Swing GUI. The user interface tries to display as
>   much detail as possible and tries to present a structure as close as
>   the actual Java class file structure. At the same time ease of use and
>   class file consistency while doing modifications is also stressed. For
>   example, when a method is deleted, the associated constant pool entry
>   will also be deleted if it is no longer referenced. In built verifier
>   checks changes before saving the file. This tool has been used by
>   people learning Java class file internals. This tool has also been
>   used to do quick modifications in class files when the source code is
>   not available.

> **[JBE - Java Bytecode Editor](http://set.ee/jbe/)**
>
> JBE is a bytecode editor suitable for viewing and modifying java class
>   files. It is built on top of the open-source jclasslib bytecode viewer
>   by ej-technologies. For verification and exporting the class files,
>   JBE uses the the Bytecode Engineering Library by Apache's Jakarta
>   project.

> **[Class Construction Kit](http://bcel.sourceforge.net/cck.html)**
>
> The Class Construction Kit is a tool for the visual creation or
>   modification of Java class files. It is implemented using BCEL and
>   Swing.

> **[reJ](http://rejava.sourceforge.net/)**
>
> The reJ project aims to allow improved visibility into Java class files, whether they were created compiling from Java
>   sources, another language or by any other kind of tool. Basically
>   anything that will run in a Java Virtual Machine.
>   reJ is a library and a graphical tool for inspection (viewing,
>   searching and comparing) and manipulation (modification, obfuscation,
>   refactoring of methods, fields, attributes and code) of classfiles for
>   the Java platform.

> **[BcelEditor](https://forum.tuts4you.com/topic/34344-bceleditor-10/)**
>
> BcelEditor is a tool for the visual modification of Java class files.
>   It is implemented using BCEL. 
>   
> <sub>Note: You need to register on the site to get access</sub>

> **[MethodBodyEditor for Java](https://forum.tuts4you.com/topic/33703-methodbodyeditor-for-java/)**
>
> A Java class editor 
> <sub>Note: You need to register on the site to
>   get access</sub>

Other than this, some other generic java tools are available on [tuts4you](https://forum.tuts4you.com/)

Comment: Man! ReJ is awesome! I guess this is the best it gets for editing jars. I might create a tool, but I'd need so much reflection... Anyway, thank you. I'll definitely use these tools for the foreseeable future.